# Не создается делегат для EventHandler<TEventArgs>

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

Я пытаюсь создать делегат для EventHandler, но в обобщенном случае. Т.е. я ищу по названию событие, метод, и

```
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(handlerType, action);
```

action, это MethodInfo для

```
public void OnMD(object sender, MouseMoveEventArgse)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Here");
}
```

само событие это

```
public event EventHandler<MouseMoveEventArgs> MouseEnter;
```

В итоге после первого кода вылезает:

System.ArgumentException: "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: handlerType - что такое?

Comment: @Grundy  var targetEvent = oType.GetEvent(propery.Key.Name);
 var handlerType = targetEvent.EventHandlerType;

Comment: Примеры https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=net-7.0#system-delegate-createdelegate(system-type-system-reflection-methodinfo) вполне себе понятные и работоспособные

Comment: @rotabor я по этому гайду и делал. Тут проблема в том, что я не могу прописать в ручную typeof(EventHandler<MouseMoveEventArgs>). При том, если добавлять делегат-метод на это событие через +=, то все работает.

Comment: `Delegate.CreateDelegate(handlerType, x, action)` - сработает такая перегрузка. Где `x` - целевой объект (может быть просто `null`).

Comment: Я поставил минус за вопрос потому, что в нём очень мало подробностей.

Comment: А в чём смысл то этого всего? Чем `+=` не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример от Microsoft с добавлением вашего типа:

```
using System.Reflection;
public class Base {}
public class Derived : Base {
    public static Derived MyMethod(Base arg) {
            Base dummy = arg;
            Console.WriteLine("MyMethod");
            return new Derived();
        }
    public static void A(object o, MouseMoveEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
}
public class MouseMoveEventArgs {}
public delegate Base Example(Derived arg);
public class bp {
    static void Main() {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
        MethodInfo minfo = typeof(Derived).GetMethod("MyMethod", flags);
        var ex1 = (Example)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Example), minfo);
        Base b = ex1(new Derived());
        minfo = typeof(Derived).GetMethod("A");
        var ex2 =
            (EventHandler<MouseMoveEventArgs>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler<MouseMoveEventArgs>), minfo);
        ex2(new object(), new MouseMoveEventArgs());
    }
}
```

Работает. Возможно, у вас не хватает знака '?' (я сделал пример на FW 4.8 c# 5):

```
public void OnMD(object? sender, MouseMoveEventArgs e)
```

**UPD** Ну, тогда так (насколько я понял вашу задачу):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
public class I {
    int _i;
    public int iI { get { return _i; } set { _i = value; SetEvt(new object(), _i); } }
    public int Inc() { _i++; IncEvt(new object(), _i.ToString()); return _i; }
    public int Dec() { _i--; DecEvt(new object(), new EventArgs()); return _i; }
    public event EventHandler<int> SetEvt;
    public event EventHandler<string> IncEvt;
    public event EventHandler DecEvt;
}
public class EventHandlers {
    public void M1(object o, int e) { Console.WriteLine("M1: {0}", e); }
    public void M2(object o, int e) { Console.WriteLine("M2: {0}", e); }
    public void M3(object o, string e) { Console.WriteLine("M3: {0}", e); }
    public void M4(object o, string e) { Console.WriteLine("M4: {0}", e); }
    public void M5(object o, EventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine("M5"); }
    public void M6(object o, EventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine("M6"); }
}
public class bp {
    static void Main() {
        var evts = new string[] { "SetEvt", "IncEvt", "DecEvt" };
        var hndlrs = new string[] { "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6" };
        var i = new I(); var ehs = new EventHandlers();
        var ei = typeof(I).GetEvent(evts[0]);
        ei.AddEventHandler(i
            , Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, ehs, hndlrs[1], true));
        i.iI = 3;
        ei = typeof(I).GetEvent(evts[1]);
        ei.AddEventHandler(i
            , Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, ehs, hndlrs[2], true));
        ei.AddEventHandler(i
            , Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, ehs, hndlrs[3], true));
        i.Inc();
        ei = typeof(I).GetEvent(evts[2]);
        ei.AddEventHandler(i
            , Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, ehs, hndlrs[5], true));
        i.Dec();
    }
}
```

-->

M2: 3

M3: 4

M4: 4

M6

И вы же понимаете, что сигнатура делегата должна соответствовать сигнатуре события? Как попало назначать обработчики событиям не получится.

Comment: Я пробовал с ?, но не сработало. И я не могу использовать typeof(Example), т.к. я получаю событие и делегат через GetEvent("eventName") и EventHandlerType. Если бы все было так просто в моем случае.

Comment: Поясню еще глубже: у меня есть файлик где написано текстом у какого события какой обработчик в стиле `EventName="MethodName"` и по EventName я ищу в объекте событие, а по MethodName 
в другом объекте обработчик для этого события

Comment: Обновил ответ, предлагаю решение.

Comment: Честно говоря, по логике, все работает, но ничего не работает. Т.е. Обработчик вроде добавляется, но когда я смотрю, где он вызывается, то моё событие null. Но мне кажется, что это не в этом дело. Вероятно что то со ссылками и дотнетовской системой. Надеюсь это так

Comment: Вас тяжело понять. Возьмите мою последнюю программу и исправьте так, чтобы показать, что вам нужно. Или, наконец-то, покажите свой код.

Comment: Чтож, по факту я вашем методом забиндил, я попробовал искусственно вызвать событие, и оно сработало, что важно.  За это вам большое спасибо. Но дальше жесть какая то. Я создал в базовом классе `public bool IsEME => MouseEnter != null;` на событие `MouseEnter`. В начале он показывает true, после того как назначил, но потом в одном методе он просто становиться false. Сложно объяснить, но... Могу показать, снять ролик

Comment: Кино без сценария не поможет. И спасибо в карман не положишь :-)

Comment: Кроме кина есть [гит](https://github.com/Domvogne/MakeUI), если поможет. И [кино](https://youtu.be/AgRROup9d4A) Если будете мучиться то проект Experiments

Comment: Не, мучиться не буду. Давайте уж дальше сами.

Comment: Ваше право на не мучиться принято)

Comment: Почему вы C# форматируете как JavaScript? Тяжело читать.

Comment: @aepot мне так удобно. На JS никогда не программировал.