# Создать делегат с аргументами, тип которых передан в виде строк

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно создать делегат с указанным типом возврата и аргументов (ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО в виде строк)

пример:
`CreateDelegate("int", new string[]{"string", "bool", "bool"});`

```cs
public static ??? CreateDelegate(string returnType, string[] arguments){ 
    //создать делегат 
}
```

Comment: А зачем? А методы под этот делегат тоже подобным образом задавать, или они как-то жёстко запрограммированы, и, соотвественно, все делегаты можно тоже задать?

Comment: @rotabor это нужно для вызова функции из DLL. Название функции и путь к DLL - строки и могут быть любыми

Comment: Можно сделать кастомное решение, но придется и свой тип реализовывать и другое. Делегат - это ссылка. А ее создать и аллоцировать под нужды работы навряд ли можно.

Comment: Вроде ж недавно был такой вопрос?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1533185/184217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, решение было найдено.
Код на GitHub: https://github.com/nekit270ch/dllcaller

Метод `CreateDelegate(string returnType, string[] argumentTypes)` создает сборку с помощью AssemblyBuilder. В ней с помощью TypeBuilder, ConstructorBuilder и MethodBuilder создается тип делегата с указанными типом возврата и аргументов. Строки конвертируются в типы через `Type.GetType`.

Полный код метода:

```
private static Type CreateDelegate(string returnType, string[] argumentTypes){
    Type delegateReturnType = Type.GetType(returnType);

    Type[] delegateArgumentTypes = new Type[argumentTypes.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < argumentTypes.Length; i++){
        delegateArgumentTypes[i] = Type.GetType(argumentTypes[i]);
    }

    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicDelegate", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(MulticastDelegate));

    ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(IntPtr) });
    constructorBuilder.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.Runtime | MethodImplAttributes.Managed);

    MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Invoke", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual, delegateReturnType, delegateArgumentTypes);
    methodBuilder.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.Runtime | MethodImplAttributes.Managed);

    Type delegateType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
    return delegateType;
}
```

Comment: А чем это круче, чем однострочник `return Expression.GetDelegateType(arguments.Append(returnType).Select(Type.GetType).ToArray());`?

Comment: @aepot тем, что не выдает `System.ArgumentException: Заданный тип не должен быть определением базового типа` в `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`, где я его и использую